# Регулярное выражение на проверку последовательности неповторяющихся цифр

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Необходимо проверить на длину строки `(4)` и чтобы строка не содержала последовательно повторяющиеся цифры. То есть такого не должно быть `1111`

Сперва проверяю если строка точно содержит 4 цифры `^(?=\d{4}$)` а далее пока не получается придумать

**UPDATE:**

```
Получилось вот такой регуляркой, правда не оч компактной
^(?=\d{4}$)(?!1{4}|2{4}|3{4}|4{4}|5{4}|6{4}|7{4}|8{4}|9{4}|0{4})([1-9]\d+$)
```

Comment: А 1212 может быть?

Comment: А далее проверяйте, что в строке нет соответствий шаблону `(.)\1`

Comment: Да главное чтобы одна цифра не повторялась все 4 раза

Comment: @quaresma89 а 1112 может?

Comment: Да и такой вариант возможен

Comment: Все четыре раза – значит `(.)\1\1\1`

Comment: Можно завернуть всё в одну регулярку, но она получится громоздкая, я бы не стал, левое последовательно проверить две

Comment: Только что заметил что не добавил в вопросе, цифры от 1-9 не только 1111 не могут повторяться но и другие

Comment: Вы пробовали мою регулярку? \1 – это номер группы, а не поиск цифры "1"

Comment: Да попробовал, если ввожу 1234 не находит совпадений

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/pnMSuR/1

Comment: Ну и не должен, вы же прочитали что я написал? И да, эту штуку `1{4}|2{4}|3{4}|4{4}|5{4}|6{4}|7{4}|8{4}|9{4}|0{4}` можно заменить на мою конструкцию, проверьте, собственно чуть выше вам дали пример

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как ограничить строку только 4мя цифрами вы уже в курсе, так что остается только сначала применить негативный просмотр вперед `(?!___)`, исключив повторы. Для этого надо взять первую цифру у группу захвата `(\d)`, а потом сослаться на нее через номер `\1`, повторив недостающие 3 раза `{3}`.

```
^(?!(\d)\1{3})\d{4}$
```

Answer (score 1):

Регулярное выражение, которое найдёт совпадение целой строки из 4 цифр, начинающихся с ненулевой цифры, исключая строки с одинаковыми цифрами:

```
^([1-9])(?!\1+$)\d{3}$
```

- `^` - начало строки
- `([1-9])` - захватывающая подмаска №1, находит и сохраняет в своём буфере одну цифру от `1` до `9`
- `(?!\1+$)` - отмена совпадения при наличии сразу после текущей позиции 1 и более повторов цифры, захваченной в подмаске №1
- `\d{3}` - любые три цифры
- `$` - конец строки.

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/F3H97f/2/)